# How to get value of buttons in a PHP foreach loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, foreach

I'm working on a very simple social media webapp to practice PHP & Ajax. Users get some friend suggestions, and when they send a request I want the recipient to get a little notification using Ajax.

The request button is in a foreach loop, like so:

```
<?php foreach ($suggestions as $suggestion) : ?>
   [...]
   <form action="" method="post" id="formRequest">
      <input type="hidden" name="userID" class="userID" value="<?php echo $userID ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="buddyID" class="buddyID" value="<?php echo $suggestion['userID'] ?>">
      <input type="submit" value="Add as friend" name="request" class="request">
   </form>
```

To test if Ajax gets the right buddyID value when I click 'Add' a specific user, I have tried this:

```
let request = document.querySelector(".request");

   request.addEventListener("click", function() {
      let buddyID = document.querySelector(".buddyID").value;
      console.log(buddyID);
   })
```

but this only logs the first suggested buddy's ID (so only when I click the first button); the console stays empty when I add the 2nd or 3rd suggested buddy.
My guess is I'll have to use a for loop, but when I tried to add one it wouldn't print anything at all.

Comment: for the recipient to get a notification via Ajax you would need to poll frequently. Rather than doing that you could consider `Server Sent Events` or `websockets`. As for the problem itself - the event listener is not being registered for ALL buttons, only one. Use something like `querySelectorAll` to find a list of buttons and assign the listener to each

Comment: incidentally you cannot repeat element IDs so you should remove it from the form. As you intend to use AJAX there is no need for the forms at all - a series of buttons ( one per record ) with custom `dataset` attributes such as `data-buddy` or `data-user` ) in conjunction with the event listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to assign the `click` event listener to all the buttons rather than just to one you could try something like this using `querySelectorAll` to find the nodelist through which you iterate.

```
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="submit"].request' ) ).forEach( bttn=>{
    bttn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();

        let buddyID=e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.buddyID').value;
        let userID=e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.userID').value;

        console.info( buddyID, userID );
    });
});
```

You could simplify things further by removing the forms ( which don't really do anything here anyway if you use AJAX ) and simply have a singular button per record / suggestion that has the necessary information assigned to it in the form of `dataset` attributes.

```
<?php
    foreach( $suggestions as $suggestion ) { 
?>

    <input class="request" type='button' data-buddyID="<?php echo $suggestion['userID'];?>" data-userID="<?php echo $userID;?>" value="Add as friend" />

<?php
    }
?>



Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="button"].request' ) ).forEach( bttn=>{
    bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let buddyID=this.dataset.buddyID;
        let userID=this.dataset.userID;

        console.info( buddyID, userID );
    });
});
```